# MySQL Workbench failing to connect via SSH due to key

Tags: mysql-workbench, ssh-keys

Trying to create a remote management connection to the MySQL server via MySQL Workbench v6.3.5 gets me an "ERROR Could not establish SSH connection: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey'])." error message.

I've already tried the workarounds published on [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527743/mysql-workbench-version-6-0-8-ssh-authentication-issue), and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512324/mysql-workbench-ssh-connection-error-bad-authentication-typeallowed-types-pu) but can't get it to work.

The SSH key works fine to establish a command-line connection via OpenSSH on terminal, but Workbench is unable to accept it.

Comment: ...did you find a solution, I have same problem?

Comment: Still far, I'm afraid; exported the .sql file and imported in phpMyAdmin on the server to get it work.  Now in the server, I can work with it and sync it, but couldn't make it connect with the public keys.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I have a solution that worked for me.

You cannot password protect the key.

It must be exported in Open SSH format.

Generate a new public key without a password and add it to your server. Then export it in openssh format and use that in MySQL workbench.

Let me know

Comment: I could use a password protected key and MySQL Workbench prompted for the password. Still - the Open SSH format did the trick for me.

Comment: Which MySQL Workbench version do you use?

Comment: `It must be exported in Open SSH format.` <--- THIS! (even can be protected) Thanks a lot!

Comment: "You cannot password protect the key." This is what sorted it for me. I'm on Mac OS and thus my key was already OpenSSH. The key worked everywhere else, including Sequel Pro, but not in MySQL Workbench. As soon as I made a second key without a password, the tunnel worked. =/

Comment: I use MobaXterm KeyGen utility. I had to create a new key without a passphrase and convert it to Open SSH format, thanks @Hugo14453

Answer (score 1):

The bug was reported here for MySQL Workbench 6.3.8, 6.3.9 on Microsoft Windows: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83485 (you can subscribe for email updates).