# Can't connect to MySql DB through ssh usign Workbench after update

Tags: mysql, ssh, key-pair

I'm facing a strange problem here...

My database is in a AWS EC2 and I was used to connect to it through SSH using MySql Workbenh.
To do it, I generated a **passphrase protected ppk file** using `puttygen` on ubuntu 16.04 and it worked fine.

But after an update, using the same configuration, I receive this error message:

> **Could not connect the SSH Tunnel**
>
> Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are
>   correct and try again. Details (Original exception message): Bad
>   authentication type, the server is not accepting this type of
>   authentication. Allowed ones are:  [u'publickey']

So, searching on Google I found this two guys with the same problem: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504232/mysql-workbench-failing-to-connect-via-ssh-due-to-key), and [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cannot-connect-to-mysql-workbench).

The solution proposed is generate a **public open-ssh** file and use it, then it was I did:

```
puttygen myKey.ppk -O public-openssh -o myKey.ppk
```

And the problem stills the same! I'm not sure if the Workbench update (it is in 6.3.10 version now) caused this issue, but before that I could connect with no problems.
I can connect normally in server through ssh in ubuntu terminal.

What I can do?

Comment: not sure SO is the place for this post.. maybe superuser?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I posted it in https://superuser.com/questions/1303388/cant-connect-to-mysql-db-through-ssh-usign-workbench-after-update

Comment: Finally I could solve this, I answered the question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1303388/cant-connect-to-mysql-db-through-ssh-usign-workbench-after-update/1303990#1303990